# ajax not working within inside click handler

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, cakephp-2.0

My database is being updated but the success callback isn't being triggered.  If I put an alert before the ajax call it works, but if I place it after the ajax call it doesn't work.  Even if it's outside the ajax function.

What should I do in order to get the success callback to trigger?

```
$('li').click(function() {
    var task_id = $(this).parent().attr("task_id");
    var task_box = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr("id");
    var new_color = $(this).attr('class');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myBaseUrl + 'tasks/updateColor',
        data: {id: task_id, color: new_color},
        success: function(response, status) {
            //$(task_box).attr('class', new_color);
            alert(response);

        },
        error: function(response, status) {
            alert(results);
            //alert('error');

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Try adding this to the ajax call and post the alert result (if any): `
complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus ) {alert(textStatus);}`

Comment: Needed to get fresh eyes.  Turns out my URL was returning unintended data.  I used this to keep that URL from actually displaying anything.
 $this->autoRender = false;

Comment: that line always helps with ajax calls :) If the error is solved, could you answer this yourself and accept it, or delete the question altogether if you think the solution won't help anyone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the controller

$this->autoRender = false;